# Can we update an existing variable in a route with GET method with the use of another route with POST method

Tags: python, flask

I have this code in flask with a route named `@app.route("/forecastReport/", methods = ['GET'])`
that has a global variable named `forecast` and Im returning it to my client side. Can I update this variable `forecast` with the use of another route named `@app.route("/updateForecastReport/", methods = ['POST'])`? so this route will receive an input from the client side and use it to update the variable `forecast`. Can we do that?

**this is a sample code:**

```
forecast= []


@app.route("/updateForecastReport/", methods = ['POST'])
def UpdateForecast():
     fetchedData = request.data.decode("UTF-8")
     fetchedData = (int(i) for i in data.strip("[]").split(","))
     # This fetchedData variable must be use to update the forecast variable in the another route

@app.route("/forecastReport/", methods = ['GET'])
def ForecastReport():
    global forecast
    return jsonify([forecast])
```

Comment: you can set the forecast variable as an attribute to the app instance like app.forecast = [] and use it then to modify things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example, maybe this helps you a little bit

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.forecast = []

@app.route("/updateForecastReport/", methods = ['POST'])
def UpdateForecast():
    fetchedData = request.data.decode("UTF-8")
    app.forecast = (int(i) for i in data.strip("[]").split(","))

@app.route("/forecastReport/", methods = ['GET'])
def ForecastReport():
    return jsonify(app.forecast)
```